# An assumption for a scenario that is typically true in practice

Tags: single-word-requests

Which adjective in the sense of 'typically true, safe to assume' fits into the following sentence:

> The crucial but _______ assumption for our experiment is that the steel sample does not contain more than 2% carbon.

Comment: reasonable or rational assumption.

Answer (score 1):

likely
or
probable

> likely
>   1. Possessing or displaying the qualities or characteristics that make something probable
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/likely)
>
> probable
>  Likely to happen or be the case.
>  [Oxford Living
>   Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/probable)

> The crucial but likely/probable assumption for our experiment is
>   that the steel sample does not contain more than 2% carbon.

Answer (score 0):

The crucial but **expected** assumption for our experiment is that the steel sample does not contain more than 2% carbon.

> Anticipated, regarded as probable or likely; predicted.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/66457?rskey=I9tW9K&result=2#eid)

> Consumer confidence rises to a better-than-**expected** 128.7 in April

[CNBC](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/04/24/consumer-confidence-at-128-point-7-in-april-vs-126-reading-expected.html)

Answer (score 0):

The crucial but **plausible** assumption...

Its meaning is perhaps slightly weaker than the required 'typically true, safe to assume'.

> - seeming likely to be true, or able to be believed
>     [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/plausible)
> - seemingly or apparently valid, likely, or acceptable; credible
> - apparently reasonable, valid, truthful, etc
> - apparently trustworthy or believable
> - having an appearance of truth or reason; credible; believable
>     [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/plausible)